# MySQL join with specific WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database

[image]

With this query I get all users and number of products they have bought:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  cd.name,
  cd.surname,
  COUNT(p.name) as bought
FROM shopping s
 JOIN client c ON s.client_id = c.id
 JOIN client_details cd ON c.id = cd.client_id
 JOIN product p ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

It's pretty good, but I have to select all users and number of specific products bought. With this query I get it only if the user have bought at least one product:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  cd.name,
  cd.surname,
  COUNT(p.name) as bought
FROM shopping s
 JOIN client c ON s.client_id = c.id
 JOIN client_details cd ON c.id = cd.client_id
 JOIN product p ON s.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'sugar'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I want to get the list with all users, and if specific user didn' buy specific product, there should be 0 on output.

Answer (score 0):

Use condition aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, cd.name, cd.surname,
       MAX(p.name = 'sugar') as SugarFlag
FROM shopping s JOIN
     client c
     ON s.client_id = c.id JOIN
     client_details cd
     ON c.id = cd.client_id JOIN
     product p
     ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```